How do we create a dynamic useState for a props inside array mapping?
thank your for reading.
I have a problem and a question.
I use Material-Tailwind navbar and a menu with submenu, and this is working perfectly.
And the problem comes when I want to create a several submenu dropown from the menu. The submenu trigger with props from Menu using open and handler using the useState and selected props from ListItem (see the code below).
My nav is displayed from mapping an array. My question is, how do we create a dynamic useState for triggering the other submenu?
Thank you for your response.
const menus = [
  {
    title: "About",
    submenu: [
      {
        subtitle: "Submenu 1-1",
      },
      {
        subtitle: "Submenu 1-2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "Contact Us",
    submenu: [
      {
        subtitle: "Submenu 2-1",
      },
      {
        subtitle: "Submenu 2-2",
      },
    ],
  },
]

function NavList() {
 const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);
 const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = useState(false);


{menus.map((menu, key) => (
    <React.Fragment key={key}>
          {item.submenu ? (
            <>
              <Menu
                open={menuOpen}
                handler={setMenuOpen}
                allowHover={true}
              >
                <MenuHandler>
                  <Typography as="div">
                    <ListItem
                      selected={menuOpen}
                      onClick={() => setMobileOpen((cur) => !cur)}
                    >
                      {item.title}
                      <ChevronDownIcon
                        strokeWidth={2.5}
                        className={`hidden h-4 w-4 transition-transform lg:block ${
                          menuOpen ? "rotate-180" : ""
                        }`}
                      />
                      <ChevronDownIcon
                        strokeWidth={2.5}
                        className={`block h-3 w-3 transition-transform lg:hidden ${
                          setMobileOpen ? "rotate-180" : ""
                        }`}
                      />
                    </ListItem>
                  </Typography>
                </MenuHandler>
                <MenuList className="hidden min-w-fit rounded-xl p-2 px-4 lg:block">
                  <ul className="flex flex-col gap-y-2 outline-none outline-0">
                    {item.submenu.map((item, key) => (
                      <a href="#" key={key}>
                        <MenuItem className="items-center rounded-lg p-0">
                          <div>
                            <Typography
                              variant="h6"
                              className="font-medium text-light-blue"
                            >
                              {item.subtitle}
                            </Typography>
                          </div>
                        </MenuItem>
                      </a>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                </MenuList>
              </Menu>
            </>
          ) : (
            <Typography as="a" href="#">
              <ListItem className="flex items-center gap-1 py-2 pr-4">
                {item.title}
              </ListItem>
            </Typography>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
 ))}
}



What is the other submenu? In any case, you have to keep values in state variable such that they have 1:1 mapping with your submenu keys. So maybe an array of array or array of objects. If you can give more details I can help you out further

@TusharShahi thank you for your response. I am sorry my explanation does not easy to understand. So my dropdown menu is working fine when I only have one menu with sub-menu, and the problem comes when there are two menus with sub-menu (as you can see in const menus), they will trigger the dropdown at same time. My array map have a ternary which check if there are menu with sub-menu.
